# Open Link With [ ionic Mobile App or browser ] on android

Tags: android, html, ionic-framework, mobile

I'm working on ionic mobile application, I'd like to send an email containing a link. The user would have the possibility to open link on my app or in web browser, as shown in screenshot below.

If the user chooses to open the link by my mobile app, they will get a specific screen. But if they choose to open the link using browser they should be redirected to a web page.

How can I do it?

[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: OK, good luck.  (you didn't ask a question)

Comment: Updated to be clear.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about creating deep links for your app? Deep links can allow you to designate a specific uri, which when clicked on ask the user if they want to open it in your app or the browser.

Take a look at https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking